# How to add website icon in gmail google apps?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

It is possible to add the custom website icon in google app of gmail account?

I have to create the custom website icon in my gmail google apps like 'google drive','YouTube','Calendar' etc. If I click on that icon the custom website will be open in new tab with login authentication/after login dashboard i.e don't need to login again on custom website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Gmail button like Save to Drive button from Drive API. However, given your use case, it seems that the [Google Sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) can work for you. It works just like you describe, there's a button and when you click it, it will handle the process of sign-in for you.

To [integrate Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) button:
You must include the Google Platform Library on your web pages that integrate Google Sign-In.

1. **Specify your app's client ID**

Specify the client ID you created for your app in the Google Developers Console with the google-signin-client_id meta element.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

2. **Add a Google Sign-In button**

< div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">

3. **Add a Google Sign-In button**

< div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">